# Additional Fields aren't sent within Contact Form email

Tags: form, emails, plugin-contactform

I am using Contact Form v1.9.0 with latest version of Craft.
I've additional fields to the form so that the inputted values appear in the email message. However, the only field being sent within the message is the `message[body]` field.

A link to a gist of my form code is below:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f380c316ad14864aed7aa95dbb2cafc8

I am using jquery to copy and replace the value of `fromName` and `fromEmail`, which you'll see are hidden fields.

This exact form has been used on numerous sites in the past few months, using Contact Form 1.8.1.

Any thoughts on why those additional fields aren't being attached to the email message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is this:

```
<textarea name="message" name="message[body]" cols="30" rows="6" placeholder="Questions or Comments"></textarea>
```

You're defining `name` twice.  The 2nd one gets ignored (which is required if you're using the array syntax for other fields).

Comment: So it was my html after all. I QUIT!  Thanks Brad

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure it's this, but you've got a couple of fields with spaces in their names:

```
message[First Name] 
message[Last Name]
```

I'd probably get rid of those spaces or at least enclose them in quotes first, see if that improves things. Other than that I couldn't spot anything obvious.

Comment: It isn't that. However, I did try both options and those additional fields still do not come within the email.

Comment: I thought it was a long shot, never mind. At least it looks like Brad got you sorted.

Comment: Steve, appreciate your help. Brad did get me sorted and made me realize how blind I am, lol.